# Using Chef to install remote zip from a web location

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef. Can anyone let me know the best way to write a recipe to copy a file from external web server?
From: https://openhardwaremonitor.org/files/openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6.zip

and unzip it?

I was thinking of invoking a powershell command but am unsure on the best approach to do so. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [archive_file resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file/) (chef-client version >= 15). You can use this to extract Zip files.

So, this will be a two step process:

- Download the file from URL to local path
- Extract the file to required path

Example:

```rb
remote_file 'C:/Users/Public/openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6.zip' do
  source 'https://openhardwaremonitor.org/files/openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6.zip'
end

archive_file 'C:/Users/Public/openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6.zip' do
  destination 'C:/hardwaremon'
end
```